Microsoft Dataverse Dependent Plugin (Package) and Profiling & Debugging
I am using Dependent Plugin but unable to Plugin Profile. Is there some other way to debug the plugin code when deployed as Package

You can try updating the appsettings.json of the PluginRegistrationTool
(C:\Users<your-user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\PowerPlatform\PRT\9.1.0.187\tools)
{
  "PluginNupkg": true,
  "LegacyPluginProfiler": false
}

